# Conditioning on a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

Let $X, Y$ denote random variables. Let $f(\cdot)$ denote a real-value function. I know that
$$P(X|Y, f(Y))$$
is equivalent to $$P(X|Y).$$

Now suppose I have

$$P(X|a \leq Y \leq b, f(Y))$$

where $a, b$ are constants. Is this equal to

$$P(X|a \leq Y \leq b)?$$

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: While "$\mathbb P(X \mid Y)$" is meaningful, some people thing a bare "$X \mid Y$" is not.  Even for those who are less fussy, "$X \mid a \leq Y \leq b$" is very difficult to read.  Is "$a \leq Y \leq b$" supposed to be a random variable or an event?

Comment: @Henry, it is supposed to be an event.

Comment: @Devon $P(X|a\leq Y\leq b)$ doesn't have any meaning. The expression $P(X=1|a\leq Y\leq b)$ does, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As an example, suppose

- $Y=-1$, $0$, $1$ with equal probabilities $\frac13$,
- $X=Y$
- $f(Y)=Y$
- $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Then

- $P(X=x \mid 0≤Y≤1,f(Y)) = \mathbf{1}_{[Y=x]}$, i.e. $1$ when $Y=x \in \{0,1\}$ and $0$ otherwise
- $P(X=x \mid 0≤Y≤1) = \frac12$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$ and $0$ otherwise

and these are not the same

Comment: In the first case where we have $P(X| a \leq Y \leq b, f(Y)) = P(X|a \leq Y \leq b, Y)$, isn't the intersection between $\{a \leq Y \leq b, Y\} = \{a \leq Y \leq b\}?$ Therefore, $P(X|a \leq Y \leq b , Y) = P(X|a \leq Y \leq b)$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Devon You cannot really have an intersection between an event and a random variable.  You could say that the intersection between the event $a \le Y \le b$ and the event $Y=y$ is $Y=y$ if $a \le y \le b$ and is empty otherwise.

Comment: I see. I think I am little bit confused by the notation. Suppose I wrote $P(X = x | \{Y: a \leq Y \leq b\}, f(Y) = f(y)) = P(X = x | \{Y: a \leq Y \leq b\}, Y=y)$. Would this be equal to $P(X = x|Y: a \leq Y \leq b)$? Or is it more correct to write $P(X =x|Y=y: a \leq y \leq b)$?